# RethinkDB connection issue

Tags: node.js

I am trying one example from [Building an earthquake map with RethinkDB and GeoJSON](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/earthquake-geojson/)

for that i installed RethinkDB and after running the example i am getting below error

```
 [RqlDriverError: Could not connect to localhost:28015.
connect ECONNREFUSED]
  name: 'RqlDriverError',
  msg: 'Could not connect to localhost:28015.\nconnect ECONNREFUSED',
  message: 'Could not connect to localhost:28015.\nconnect ECONNREFUSED'
```

from above error one can easily determine that this is connection problem.
Please help me out with some solutions

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to start the rethinkdb in another tab of terminal.